# hola me podrian decir que hago si python no encuentra mi modulo pygame

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
me sale ese error que hago

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es mi codigo donde importo el pygame

Comment: Has revisado que si este instalado correctamente?

Comment: Subir imágenes de código y de mensajes de error es [mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Lee [ask] y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Lo primero que se me ocurre como te comentaron es ver si tienes instalada la librería, ¿estás haciendo algún tutorial? suele pasar que en estos omiten la parte de instalar las librerías para que funcionen. Prueba ejecutar en una terminar **pip install pygame**

Answer (score 1):

Intenta verificar que previamente esta instalado el modulo esto lo puedes hacer desde terminal:

```
pip freeze desde la consola(cmd)
pip list desde la consola(cmd)
```

En caso de que no se muestre en el listado lo que tendrás que hacer es instalarlo con:

```
pip install pygame
```